# MATLAB - factor-out scale factor from column matrix

Tags: matlab

I have this column matrix:

```matlab
syms a;
syms b;
myColVector = [-a; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; -b];
```

I am more interested in the factor of the vector which is -1, how can I achieve this?

I have tried `eig(...)` function but it didn't work. I also tried the `factor(...)` command and it didn't work either.

**Edit:**

Say the function that I am looking for is called `findFactor`. If I type:

`findFactor(myColVector)`,

then this should output `-1`.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are expecting to see, I don't quite understand your question?

Comment: @user12339314 please see my edit.

Comment: What should you get as output for your `findFactor` function if your vector is `myColVector = [-a; a; 0; 0; 0; 0; a; -b];`?

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, well, there is no factors to factor-out, so just +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> findSymType(myColVector,'constant')


ans =

[ -1, 0]
```

Not exactly what you are looking for because it also finds the constant "0", but I guess it's close enough to allow you proceeding.